# How do I check at compile-time if there's enough `{}` placeholders for all arguments?

Tags: c++, fmt, stdformat

[`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) has a (compile-time and runtime) format string validation, but one thing not included in this validation is whether there are enough `{}` placeholders for all arguments (excessive arguments are silently ignored).

I assume this could be useful in some rare cases (e.g if you generate the format string), but I don't need it, and I've had a few bugs because of this.

Is there anything I can do to check for this compile-time? Possibly by wrapping `std::format` in my own function.

Example:

```
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::format("{} {}", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) << '\n'; // Prints `1 2`, no error!
}
```

**NOTE:** `std::format` **does** have compile-time format string validation. They just don't check for this specific issue (excessive arguments).

Comment: For std::format you would have to provide everything at compile time so that checking is allready there.

Comment: @PepijnKramer This specific thing is not included in the validation, see example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1q1fGc4Ph

Comment: Huh, I did not expect that. So I learned something ;)

Comment: While compilers generally can check it for `printf` or `scanf` and their families, you have to remember that those checks came rather late in the compiler evolution. It might take time before compilers will be able to check for `std::format` format strings.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `std::format` already checks the format string at compile-time using C++20 `consteval` magic. It's just that this specific problem isn't checked. While the compilers might add a warning for this eventually, it should also be possible to do this check from code alone (probably by wrapping `std::format_string<...>` in your own class).

Comment: Not sure, what the status is here, but: https://www.zverovich.net/2017/11/05/compile-time-format-strings.html

Comment: @Sedenion Please note, `std::format` does have compile-time format string validation. It's just that they consider this specific thing (excessive arguments) to not be an error.

Comment: FYI https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/492

Comment: Tried a few ways but it seems that the issue is `std::format` is not failing in a SFINAE-friendly way.

Answer (score 3):

You might indeed add wrappers:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct my_format_string
{
    consteval my_format_string(const char* s) :
        my_format_string(std::format_string<Ts...>(s))
    {}

    consteval my_format_string(const std::format_string<Ts...> s) : s(s)
    {
        // Use proper validation check

        // placeholder validation of the placeholders
        if (std::count(s.get().begin(), s.get().end(), '{') != sizeof...(Ts)) {
            throw 42;
        }
    }
    constexpr auto get() const { return s; }

    std::format_string<Ts...> s;
};


template <typename... Ts>
auto my_format(my_format_string<std::type_identity_t<Ts>...> format, Ts... args)
{
    return std::vformat(format.getS().get(), std::make_format_args(args...));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K3qeP9Wj9)

Comment: This is too ad hoc. It fails for e.g. `my_format("{0}{0}", 42)`.

Comment: Hmm. This will work most of the time, but I think the formatters can consume as many `{` `}` from the format string as they want, not necessarily matching the number of arguments. Also `{` `}` can be escaped by duplicating, that would need to be handled too. Also `my_format` can call `std::format` directly, to benefit from the stock validation at compile-time.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: My validation is a placeholder. std validation is done in `std::format_string`, not in `std::format`.

Comment: Is the question about "write a validator", or "how to make the check compile time?"

Comment: *"validation is done in std::format_string"* Ah, yep, I didn't realize you were inheriting from it. *"Is the question about ..., or ..."* Primarily about writing the validator. Emitting errors from `consteval` functions isn't hard...

Comment: Most people have difficulty with `constexpr` stuff.

Comment: Doing that check requires a rewrite(redesign) of the `format` library. A distinct validator must redo the parsing and track the argument references. It's not an easy task.