# Why isn't it an error if the arguments are more than required in std::format?

Tags: c++, c++20, standards, type-safety, compile-time-type-checking

The [cppref page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) on `std::format` says:

> It is not an error to provide more arguments than the format string requires:

```
// OK, produces "Hello world!"
std::format("{} {}!", "Hello", "world", "something");
```

Since `std::format` has a compile-time check to see if `fmt` and arguments mismatch, why isn't the example code above taken as an error?

**What's the rationale behind?**

Comment: "Since std::format has a compile-time check to see if fmt and arguments mismatch" It's because the format string is not required to be available at compile time and it would be a bit annoying if it worked differently for dynamic and static strings.

Comment: No matter `fmt` is static or dynamic, `std::format("{} {}!", "Hello", "world", "something");` seems buggy, and the programmer should be notified. And consider `std::format("{}{}", "Hello")` is explicitly an error.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI yes, because it would be super annoying if this is OK: `format(msg, arg1, arg2)` but it's not OK to write `format("value of msg", arg1, arg2)`. If it's not an error to not use all arguments in the dynamic case (which it's not, for good reason – this would make cases like translation where you might not need all arguments for all languages super annoying), it shouldn't be an error statically either.

Comment: Dynamic strings are actually not allowed in std::format (you need std::vformat for that). The reason why extra arguments are allowed in both cases has nothing to do with compile-time vs run-time checks.

Comment: I didn't even see that this was changed, appears to be a new constraint in C++23? Very odd change.

Comment: If I was to post this as an answer, it would be frowned upon; therefore, here it is as a comment: _**The spec allows this due to capriciousness.**_

Comment: It's not capriciousness just because one finds the result disagreeable. :) It was a fairly well thought out decision. There are some trade-offs and the choice was reasonable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check at compile-time if there's enough \`{}\` placeholders for all arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77617915/how-do-i-check-at-compile-time-if-theres-enough-placeholders-for-all-argum)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A couple of reasons.

1. You can use the same argument any number of times in the format string:

   ```
    std::fomat("{1},{0},{1}", x, y);
   ```

   There is no reason to exclude mentioning it zero times.
2. It actually comes handy in providing localized strings:

   ```
    std::vformat(get_string("Preheat the oven to {} degrees"), temp, temp*9/5+32);
   ```

   The string returned by `get_string` would contain either `{0}` or `{1}`.

Note this has nothing to do with having or not having compile-time or run-time checks. It is (should be) either considered an error or not, regardless of which checks are performed when.

Comment: Point 2 is useless since this format string is only runtime evaluated so no checks can be performed at compile time (no matter if there is to many or not enough arguments).

Comment: @MarekR Checks could have been performed at run time, but they are not, for the reason given. Actually the phrasing in the original question "Since std::format has a compile-time check" is dubious. If it should be an error, then it should be an error regardless of having or not having compile-time checks.

Comment: Neither point 1 nor point 2 are valid.  Point 1 is about the ability to pass _**fewer**_ arguments, but the question is asking why the spec allows _**more**_ arguments. Point 2 is about `vformat()` but the question is about `format()`.

Comment: @MikeNakis Point 2 is not. First, the compile-time and run-time versions really should have the same requirements - but also you could still do translation via `format` (not `vformat`) by way of a template parameter or the preprocessor.